# About an "Auto-build" System

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation

I have some projects which I wrote in C++ and compile with Visual Studio 2005. I'm using SVN for source control. Could you recommend an auto-build system to compile my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cruisecontrol or Cruisecontrol.net are both good for this kind of task.  You can use them either alone or in partnership with a build (not autobuild) tool e.g. ant or nant.

(They are both free).

Don't be put off by their java or .net basis, either will happily allow you to build visual studio c++ from svn.

see

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET

Comment: I've been using CruiseControl.net for a while now, it's very easy to get up and running, it's also very powerful. Certainly worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

FinalBuilder is second to none, check it: http://www.finalbuilder.com/